# Spectral decomposition of a time dependent operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, linear-algebra, density-operator

Let $M$ be an operator with spectral decomposition $$M(0) = \sum_{i = 1}^n  \lambda_i \left|{m_i(0)}\right\rangle\left\langle{m_i(0)}\right|.$$ To find $M(t)$, I know that $M(t) = U^{\dagger} M(0) U$. Now the right hand side becomes $$ \sum_{i = 1}^n  \lambda_i U^{\dagger} \left|{m_i(0)}\right\rangle\left\langle{m_i(0)}\right| U $$ which is $$\sum_{i = 1}^n  \lambda_i \left|{m_i(-t)}\right\rangle\left\langle{m_i(-t)}\right| .$$ It looks that $M(t)$ on the left is equal to $M(-t)$ on the right hand side.

Comment: You're forgetting the eigenvalues are a function of time too, so you conclusion doesn't follow.

Comment: @knzhou Unitary evolution does change eigenvalues.

Comment: @Seeker Just because the eigenstates evolve backwards in time relative to the Schroedinger picture it doesn't mean that you have $M(-t)$ on the right hand side.

Comment: @udrv Yeah, that was my point, the eigenvalues of the two sides don't line up.

Comment: Thank you very much friends. The point is ( correct me if I am wrong ) we should not treat |m(0)><m(0)| as density matrix but as an operator. So U^\dagger  |m(0)><m(0)| U  = |m(t)><m(t)|  and this way we have no disagreement.

Comment: @knzhou I have no idea why my first comment says "does change eigenvalues" when I meant "doesn't change eigenvalues", but yeah, "unitary evolution _doesn't_ change eigenvalues".

Comment: @udrv Whoops, you're totally right!

Comment: @Seeker Yes, correct, that always works.

Comment: I am looking for some literature in support of my last comment. If someone finds some relevant stuff, please post it here.